# public static extern uint SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int unMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I have my code like below

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
public static extern uint SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int unMsg, IntPtr wParam, 
    IntPtr lParam);
```

Fxcop error : "As it is declared in your code, the return type of P/Invoke 'SendMessage(IntPtr, int, IntPtr, IntPtr)' will be 4 bytes wide on 64-bit platforms. This is not correct, as the actual native declaration of this API indicates it should be 8 bytes wide on 64-bit platforms. Consult the MSDN Platform SDK documentation for help determining what data type should be used instead of 'uint'"

So to fix the above error do i need to change the return type UIntPtr ?

Please help me in fixing this and give me valid reasons.

Thanks,
VMG

Comment: It is an entirely correct warning.  The return type must be `IntPtr`.

Comment: `SendMessage` must be one of the most fequently P/Invoked methods in the native API. As such, the notes over on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/sendmessage.html) seem to be quite good and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The message is correct. The function returns `LRESULT` which is a signed, pointer sized type. So in C# you should use `IntPtr`.

Strictly speaking, the message parameter is unsigned, `WPARAM` is unsigned and `LPARAM` is signed, so if you wish to follow suit then you would have:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    uint Msg, 
    UIntPtr wParam, 
    IntPtr lParam
);
```

This information is all documented:

- [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx)
- [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)

However, because `SendMessage` is a one size fits all kind of a function, it's not worth getting too hung up on signed and unsigned types. Different messages treat the parameters differently, using casts. So feel free to use the types that are most convenient, modulo the fact that they must clearly be the right size.

Comment: Thanks David How you come to know return value as LRESULT ??

Comment: @user3766691 - presumably by consulting the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: From the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx